# GTK# .NET Application without requiring separate GTK# Install

Tags: c#, windows, mono, gtk#

I was playing around with developing C# apps using MonoDevelop on windows and found that I like using GTK# instead of winforms.  However, as far as I could tell so far you cannot just embed the GTK# runtime into the application.  The problem is that I would rather not have to require the end users of an app I'm working on to having to install GTK# separately... this is fine for geeks like me, but the app would be for non-geek users and I want the install to pretty much be a one click operation.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The "easy" way is to embed the Gtk# installer into your application's installer.

The harder way would be to replicate everything the Gtk# installer does in your application's installer (put files in the correct place, registry keys, PATH, etc.)

The Wix files for the Gtk# installer are here:
http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/win32-installers/