# What is the minimum software I need to install in a windows machine in order to run a mono + gtk# application?

Tags: mono, gtk#

I have developed an application with mono and I would like to know what are the minimum libraries that need to be available in a windows machine, in order to run this app.

I've heard .net will suffice, no need to install the mono package for windows. Is this true? which .net version do I have to install?

BTW, my application uses GTK# as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MonoDevelop is built on GTK#, its minimal requirements on Windows are,

- .NET Framework 4
- GTK# runtime

as stated in http://monodevelop.com/Download

Therefore, your application should require the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need [the installer present in the mono project download pages for Gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win). Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888463/).

Technically, you would need also mono, but since this is for Windows, it will include the .NET installed. Unless it is a really old version of Windows.

Hope this helps.